# Mysql - Trigger - Concat - Failed

Tags: mysql, string, triggers, var, not-exists

I have this trigger and produces the error:
The table not exist "lecturas.TablaX"

```
Begin

# Declaramos Variables
Declare MasterX,TablaX, varchar(100);

#Determinamos Master
Set MasterX =  LPAD(New.Master, 3, 0); 

#Armar Ruta
Set TablaX = Concat ( 'lecturas.M',MasterX);

# Insertar datos en la tabla Lecturas
INSERT INTO TablaX (Id) Values (New.Master);

End
```

Comment: the error says that you don't have 'tablaX' can you show create table tablax?

Comment: According to the information of MySql is not possible to have table names as variables ...